# Selecting multiple files with mouse drag in JFileChooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser

In my Java application I am using JFileChooser for choosing files from directory. I would like to select multiple files with dragging mouse over them. By default it's not working, but I enabled multiple selection. I don't know how to do it.

Is there any other way to do it or any other API? Any help will be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just hold shift / ctrl and click the mouse? to select multiple files

Comment: Holding ctrl and click over files is okay but I am talking about mouse dragging selection for multiple files.

Comment: Like holding the click button and dragging down?

Comment: Yesss...Its not working in my case.Actually I don't know JFileChooser support it or not ...

Comment: I don't believe it does... I've just tried and yeah there are no methods / anything really for that..

Comment: Is there any other way to do this stuff ??? Or any other API ??

Comment: Not that i know of... You can scroll down the pane and just hold shift and click i'm sure that would be the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching a lot I found an API namely ,

> Native Swing "The DJ Project"

In this API ,there is a class "JFileDialog" this is what i was looking for.This filedialog allows multiple selection with mouse drag and also better than Jfilechooser in the point of look and feel.But before Using this API one must have to add DJNativeSwing.jar , DJNativeSwing-SWT.jar , swt-4.3-win32-win32-x86.jar  library to the project build path and also the project should be Run with 32-bit JRE .

see this snippet of code as example from this link : https://dzone.com/articles/native-dialogs-swing-little